# Commonalities and differences between canonical structures and the implicit calculus

Tags: pl.programming-languages, type-theory, type-systems

There is a paper on [The Implicit Calculus](http://ropas.snu.ac.kr/~wclee/papers/pldi12a.pdf) as a generalization of type classes. Coq's canonical structures are also a generalization of type classes. The paper does not mention canonical structures however. The approaches seem quite similar. What are the commonalities and differences of these two approaches to generalize type classes?

Comment: I have informed the authors, who are not on cstheory. They will respond.